# What happened to the Ruby tag in the Unaswered section?

Tags: support

It use to be that when you wanted to search unanswered questions in for Ruby, you would go to the unanswered sections, and click the Ruby tag, but it isn't there anymore. As you can see in the image below, it is no longer showing up. It use to be at the very bottom, now it's gone.  What happened to it?

[image]

Comment: Presumably, it's no longer in the top twenty-five list of unanswered tags.  It simply fell off the list, due to other tags having a greater number of unanswered questions.

Comment: So that list is only a 'Top 25' and changes based on the number of tags?

Comment: based on the number of unanswered questions in the tag, I imagine.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The unanswered questions in the Ruby tag can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50

Comment: Awesome! Thank you again. If you like, create an answer for it and I'll accept, otherwise, thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) tag is apparently no longer in the top twenty five list of tags with unanswered questions.  You can find the complete list of unanswered questions in the Ruby tag by searching for [ruby] and clicking on the Unanswered tab, or by clicking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby?sort=unanswered&pagesize=50).

Note that the number of unanswered questions should place the Ruby tag at #24 in the unanswered tags.  When this sort of thing happens, you can almost always blame some form of caching.